# Is using a SVG more efficient than a PNG as a lazyload placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am using [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) lazyloading library, and *I'm trying to decide on the most performance-optimal lazyload placeholder technique*.

If the size is similar (for simplicity's sake; unlikely, as SVG is usually way smaller) **would it be more optimal for performance to use SVG or PNG**?

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="image-module aspect-ratio--4x5">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="..." src="..." data-srcset="..." srcset="...">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 204.7 255.3" width="100%" height="100%">
       <use xlink:href="#idRef" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

*"image-module" class container is just for aspect ratio

---

Related Questions:

1. I am guessing, regardless of whether SVG or PNG, I shouldn't be using them as inline element but as CSS background.  Is my guess correct and will this improve performance?
2. Is there some tool to measure the performance of paint/render differences like this?
3. I think the best, most performance-optimal method is to use **an SVG as a CSS background-image**.  However, while lazyloading the `<img>` is `opacity: 0;`, so I can't use `background-image` on the main `img`.  What I plan to do is use `background-image` on the parent, image-module classed parent, and then to target it on-load with JS. Like so:

   > ```
   > var $allImageModules = $('.image-module img');  
   > $allImageModules.on('load', function(){
   >   setTimeout(function(){
   >     $(this).parent().find('svg').remove();
   >   }, 537);
   > });
   > ```
   >
   > Is there some magical CSS way that I am not aware of to target the parent, depending on whether the class of its child image is "lazyload," "lazyloading," or "lazyloaded" class?  PS: I know `.find('svg').remove()` doesn't work.
4. Once the image is loaded, does it help performance to replace the no-longer visible background image with `background-image: none;` like below?

   > ```
   > .image-module.lazyload,
   > .image-module.lazyloading,
   > .image-module.lazyloaded {
   >     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... </svg>");
   >     background-position: center;
   >     background-size: 30%;
   >     background-repeat: no-repeat;
   > }
   > .image-module.lazyloaded {
   >     background-image: none;
   > }
   > ```

Comment: Why do you think that a background image will give you better performance than a regular image tag? Why does any of this matter, as none of this will make a significant difference in actual performance. Also, PNGs can often be much, much smaller than a similar SVG, if the image is complex.

Comment: You also need to think about CPU load - and therefore battery on mobile devices. Some SVGs take much more processing than the equivalent PNG. This is normally ok as the quicker download more than compensates ... but something to think on.

Comment: My thinking is simply SEO.  Various speed tools seem to place heavy importance on reducing server calls.  Google seems to place heavy weight on general speed optimization, among other factors.  Fewer images = fewer calls.  So, SVG instead of PNG means saving another call.  SEO is tantamount as its an ecommerce site.  I understand the difference is less than marginal when replacing 5 icons in the mobile, fixed header nav, but this is for lazyloading of like 50+ images per page.  You think it still won't matter?

Comment: I also started to worry when I updated a basic "color swatch" made of color circle product selector buttons, to select different color images of a product. I decided to get thematic and replaced the basic CSS circles with basic `<svg><use></use></svg>` vector icons of some relevant item, and now on mobile, that menu seems to cause jank.  I'd use basic CSS for lazyloading placeholder, but I want to use "complex shape"/squiggly, simple logo, so it has to be PNG or SVG.

Comment: Honestly why I was hoping someone knew of a tool to measure such differences: I seem to have a fundemental ignorance of what it entails to process an SVG vs a PNG image object.  SVGs simply seem so cool, crisp, clean and infinitely scalable, and I've seen more and more of the top dogs using them (eg, Google, Shopify, etc), so I got all excited thinking "they're super duper optimal and I'm gonna SVG everything!"  Seems I may have gotten excited too soon.